# Change Keyboard backlight timeout time

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, dell-inspiron, backlight

How to increase the timeout second/time in Windows 10.

There is no option in control panel > Hardware & Sound > Keyboard.
I have also checked the windows mobility center no keyboard option available there.

After searching for an hour I am asking this, how to change keyboard backlight timeout time in Windows 10 for Dell Laptop 5000 series.

I know that backlight does not goes off when Laptop is plugged in, give me a solution for when laptop in not plugged.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the [Dell Feature Enhancement Pack DFEP](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=T4P15)  that adds extra features for customising your hardware settings.

> Dell Feature Enhancement Pack provides OS extensions and features for Dell business client platforms, including:

- Support for hot keys and system events
- Dell customized power plans and extensions
- Battery Health Information
- Touch Palette
- **Keyboard hotkey information, including backlighting**
- Smart Settings.

After installing this, you should be able to control your keyboard backlight settings in Windows Mobility under "Dell customisation"

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the BIOS and reinstalling QuickSet to enable the options in Windows Mobility settings. I did that and was able to finally access the settings. I on the other hand am now having trouble getting the timeout to occur while i am plugged in...

Comment: Please Elaborate more, BIOS is already to latest version I check driver on the Dell Official Website, Service & support. All driver Up to Date.

What is QuickSet how to reinstall if you can mention it, it would be nice.

Comment: QuickSet is what Dell uses to make their hardware like brightness and volume keys talk with Windows. Check out C:\Program Files\Dell\QuickSet to see if you have a BacklitKB application, which is what actually configures the backlight. If you do, try opening that, and if it works then you should see a setting for the time out. Select "Never Off" instead of "10sec". I went to the Dell support site and looked up my laptop, and though it said I was all up to date, I decided to re-install the program. I selected "Drivers & Downloads", and then "Find it myself".

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same problem. Unfortunately, there is no simple option on the HP laptop. Sharing steps for HP Zbook 15. You can try similar approach for your laptop.

Steps:

1. Reboot and start tapping Esc or F10 and enter the Bios.
2. Click on ADVANCED then  Built-in Device Options.
3. Scroll down to Backlit Keyboard Timeout.
4. Hit Space and select options.
5. Press Esc and save the settings.